# Refreshing Table via AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a task to provide users a status of a backend process that runs in our application. To display this status we have created a Status table in the database that lists the tasks that have completed, failed, or are in progress, like so:

[image]

To get the most current status of this table, I am calling an `.ajax()` method every 3 seconds by wrapping the call within a `setInterval()` method. The refresh works as expected and grabs the most current status of the program, however this was my first approach at the issue and feels a little brute force-ish. I'm wondering if a better way to accomplish this exists (i.e., a cross-browser solution that mimics a live news feed with it's own API). Any thoughts?

Comment: This article explains in a much better way than i could ever explain http://techoctave.com/c7/posts/60-simple-long-polling-example-with-javascript-and-jquery/

Comment: This was a great read, thank you

Answer (score 1):

Try this http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_serversentevents.asp

sse is the best way to do it.

Try this code

```
<script>
if(typeof(EventSource) !== "undefined") {
var source = new EventSource("demo_sse.php");
source.onmessage = function(event) {
    //display data in event array.
};
} else {
//Use your old interval if SSE not support in browser
}
</script>
```

in your php code

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/event-stream');
header('Cache-Control: no-cache');//this is important

$arr=['status'=>1,'data'=>$some_array];

$retry="retry: 10000\n";
echo $.retry."data: ".json_encode($arr)."\n\n";
flush();
?>
```

you need to add "data:" in the start of you display to SSE know that is your data and "\n\n" the end of data.

and add retry, so it refresh every 10000=10 seconds

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. When you answer, please include a good explanation in your answer. Merely posting a link is not enough, as the link may no longer exist one day.

Comment: Today, nobody use IE.

Comment: Looks good, though I wonder where is a time interval set either client or server side. At least the W3 doc doesn't specify any.

Comment: @asongdoggy IE is my company's primary browser. No getting around it's compatibility

Comment: IE Not supported... However in other scenarios is very useful.

Comment: You could potentially polyfill sse for IE (https://github.com/Yaffle/EventSource/)